# How can I link a library to my executable in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have 2 libs and 1 executable in my CMakeList.txt. I would like everything linked into the executable.

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )

# Mark the language as C so that CMake doesn't try to test the C++
# cross-compiler's ability to compile a simple program because that will fail
project( jsos C ASM )
set( CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "./build/" )

# We had to adjust the CMAKE_C_FLAGS variable in the toolchain file to make sure
# the compiler would work with CMake's simple program compilation test. So unset
# it explicitly before re-setting it correctly for our system
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -nostartfiles" )

# Set the linker flags so that we use our "custom" linker script
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-T,${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/etc/linker.ld" )

add_library(duktape STATIC
  src/libs/duktape/duktape.c
)

add_library(fdlibm STATIC
  src/libs/fdlibm/e_acos.c
  src/libs/fdlibm/e_acosh.c
  src/libs/fdlibm/e_asin.c
  MORE FILES
)

add_executable(kernel
  src/start.S
  src/kernel.c
  src/cstartup.c
  src/cstubs.c
  src/rpi-gpio.c
  src/rpi-interrupts.c
  src/rpi-armtimer.c
  src/rpi-systimer.c
)

add_dependencies(kernel fdlibm duktape)

target_link_libraries(kernel fdlibm duktape)

add_custom_command(
  TARGET kernel POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ./kernel${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX} -O binary ./kernel.img
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Convert the ELF output file to a binary image"
)
```

At the moment when I link these together I get a bunch of errors like:

```
[100%] Linking C executable kernel
libduktape.a(duktape.c.obj): In function `duk_double_trunc_towards_zero':
src/libs/duktape/duktape.c:12102: undefined reference to `fabs'
src/libs/duktape/duktape.c:12102: undefined reference to `floor'
```

But `fabs` and `floor` are in `fdlibm`. `duk_double_trunc_towards_zero` is in the `duktape` library so that seemed to link OK. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try swapping libraries order in `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: @arrowd make an answer so  can accept it. This is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement:

```
target_link_libraries(kernel fdlibm duktape)
```

the external referece symbols to be resolved are searched from the ordered list of libs provided (`fdlibm duktape` in this case) in this way:

- starting from the library being linked;
- searching the symbols on the libraries on the right of it;

In your case, when resolving external symbols of `duktape` (which some are in `fdlibm`), `fdlibm`  is not even used for this search, and the symbols `duktape` requires are not found. Just putting fdlibm *after* duktape will let the symbols to be found.

For example, if you had a `fdlibm` depending on some symbols defined in `duktape`, and also the other way around, you should use:

```
target_link_libraries(kernel fdlibm duktape fdlibm)
```

so that symbols are always resolved.